# Find the count of IDs that have the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to get a count of all of the Ids that have have the same value (Drops) as other Ids. For instance, the illustration below shows you that ID 1 and 3 have A drops so the query would count them. Similarly, ID 7 & 18 have B drops so that's another two IDs that the query would count totalling in 4 Ids that share the same values so that's what my query would return.

```
+------+-------+
| ID   | Drops |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   A   |
|  2   |   C   |
|  3   |   A   |
|  7   |   B   |
| 18   |   B   |
+------+-------+
```

I've tried the several approaches but the following query was my last attempt.

```
With cte1 (Id1, D1) as 
(
    select Id, Drops
    from Posts
),
cte2 (Id2, D2) as 
(
    select Id, Drops
    from Posts
) 
Select count(distinct c1.Id1) newcnt, c1.D1 
from cte1 c1
left outer join cte2 c2 on c1.D1 = c2.D2
group by c1.D1
```

The result if written out in full would be a single value output but the records that the query should be choosing should look as follows:

```
    +------+-------+
    | ID   | Drops |
    +------+-------+
    |  1   |   A   |
    |  3   |   A   |
    |  7   |   B   |
    | 18   |   B   |
    +------+-------+
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: what is your expected output, please provide in tabular form.

Comment: What if you had another row like `19, B`?

Comment: @zealous my expected output given the above scenario would be 4 because those 4 IDs share a value with atleast another ID.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Then my expected output would be 5

Comment: @ThatGuyXY I have updated my answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to generate a list of `Drops` values that have more than one corresponding `ID` value, and then `JOIN` that to `Posts` to find all rows which have a `Drops` value that has more than one Post:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Drops
  FROM Posts
  GROUP BY Drops
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT P.*
FROM Posts P
JOIN CTE ON P.Drops = CTE.Drops
```

Output:

```
ID  Drops
1   A
3   A
7   B
18  B
```

If desired you can then count those posts in total (or grouped by `Drops` value):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Drops
  FROM Posts
  GROUP BY Drops
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS newcnt
FROM Posts P
JOIN CTE ON P.Drops = CTE.Drops
```

Output

```
newcnt
4
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d2b3/3)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `dense_rank()` to resolve your problem. if `drops` has the same ID then `dense_rank()` will provide the same rank.

Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ok4EcDcxZMEa7Cw5EQVD4Y/1).

```
with cte as
(
  select
    drops,
    count(distinct rnk) as newCnt
  from
  ( select
        *,
        dense_rank() over (partition by drops order by id) as rnk
    from myTable
  ) t
  group by
    drops
  having count(distinct rnk) > 1
)

select 
    sum(newCnt) as newCnt
from cte
```

Output:

```
   |newcnt |
   |------ |
   | 4     |
```

Answer (score 0):

First group the count of the ids for your drops and then sum the values greater than 1.

```
select sum(countdrops) as total from
(select drops , count(id) as countdrops from yourtable group by drops) as temp
where countdrops > 1;
```